# Is there a better way of modeling the routines in my operations that doesn't involve PROTECTED fields?

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns

In my application, well-defined *operations* on collections of business entities are modularized and carried out using one or more *routines*, each of which operates on a unique type of data associated with (but not necessarily contained in the objects that represent) these business entities.

A routine may have logic that must be executed before, during, or after iteration though a business entity collection. Despite specialization, each routine utilizes the id of its parent operation and that of the operation's commencing user in the logging of its work. Data (which can be of arbitrary type and cardinality) that is defined, retrieved, or produced by a given routine may also be utilized in the logging of its work.

Given such a description, a routine is represented abstractly with the following class:

```
public abstract class AbstractOperationRoutine
{
    protected final UUID parentOperationId;

    protected final User parentOperationRunCommencingUser;

    protected OperationRoutine
    (UUID parentOperationRunId, User parentOperationRunCommencingUser)
    {
        this.parentOperationRunId = parentOperationRunId;
        this.parentOperationRunCommencingUser= parentOperationRunCommencingUser;
    }

    public abstract void preExecute();
    public abstract void midExecute(BusinessEntity entity);
    public abstract void postExecute();
}
```

An example concrete routine is defined by the following class:

```
public class ConcreteOperationRoutine extends AbstractOperationRoutine
{
    private Object routineSpecificLogDataObj;

    public ConcreteOperationRoutine
    (UUID parentOperationRunId, User parentOperationRunCommencingUser)
    {
        super(parentOperationRunId, parentOperationRunCommencingUser);
    }

    //This method is used to carry out all logging in this example for 
    //the sake of simplicity; in practice, the appearance of this method
    //in a (pre/mid/post)Execute method would be replaced by one of a 
    //logging function specific to that execute method (the parameter is 
    //declared in an attempt to convey this)
    private void conductRoutineSpecificLoggingAct(int codeInt)
    {
        /*
         Code which logs work carried in out in an execute method(),
         using routineSpecificLogDataObj, parentOperationRunId,
         and parentOperationRunCommencingUser
        */
    }

    @Override
    public void preExecute()
    {
        //...
        conductRoutineSpecificLoggingAct(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void midExecute(BusinessEntity entity)
    {
        //...
        conductRoutineSpecificLoggingAct(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void postExecute()
    {
        //...
        conductRoutineSpecificLoggingAct(2);
    }

}
```

And finally, an example operation is defined by the following class:

```
public class Operation
{

    private Collection<BusinessEntity> getBusinessEntities()
    {
        //...
    }

    public void conduct(User user)
    {
        ConcreteOperationRoutine routine = 
            new ConcreteOperationRoutine(UUID.randomUUID(), user);

        routine.preExecute();

        for(BusinessEntity entity: getBusinessEntities())
            routine.midExecute(entity);

        routine.postExecute();

    }
}
```

The punishment for using `protected` fields is 100 lashes right? Well I'll take those, because I don't see a better way of modeling my routines given the data they all use to log their work. Any changes that I can think of are purely dogmatic in nature, and as such I have a hard type justifying them.

Can anyone, given the natural properties of my routines and operations, re-factor their definitions to be free of `protected` fields, all while maintaining the simplicity of their current definitions?

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, the fields of a class should ideally be used by the class itself. Additionally, the fields could also be used in the subclasses, either through getters and setters, or directly if they are declared as protected.

From your question the purposes of your API are not completely clear, but as far as I can understand, you only need `UUID` and `User` objects for logging. Anyway, I would suggest a slightly different structure:

An `OperationRoutine` interface that would force your `ConcreteOperationRoutine` classes to implement the specific set of methods:

```
public interface OperationRoutine {
    void preExecute();
    void midExecute(BusinessEntity entity);
    void postExecute();
}
```

A `LoggingHelper` class that would offer logging capabilities to all its subclasses:

```
public class LoggingHelper {
    private Object routineSpecificLogDataObj;

    private final UUID parentOperationId;
    private final User parentOperationRunCommencingUser;

    protected LoggingHelper(UUID parentOperationId, User parentOperationRunCommencingUser) {
        this.parentOperationId = parentOperationId;
        this.parentOperationRunCommencingUser = parentOperationRunCommencingUser;
    }

    protected void conductRoutineSpecificLoggingAct(int codeInt) {
        /*
         Code which logs work carried in out in an execute method(),
         using routineSpecificLogDataObj, parentOperationRunId,
         and parentOperationRunCommencingUser
        */
    }
}
```

Then, you will have your `ConcreteOperationRoutine` as an implementation of `OperationRoutine`, and it will also be subclassing the `LoggingHelper`:

```
public class ConcreteOperationRoutine extends LoggingHelper implements OperationRoutine {
    protected ConcreteOperationRoutine(UUID parentOperationId, User parentOperationRunCommencingUser) {
        super(parentOperationId, parentOperationRunCommencingUser);
    }

    public void preExecute() {
        //...
        conductRoutineSpecificLoggingAct(0);
    }

    public void midExecute(BusinessEntity entity) {
        //...
        conductRoutineSpecificLoggingAct(1);
    }

    public void postExecute() {
        //...
        conductRoutineSpecificLoggingAct(2);
    }
}
```

Finally, the `Operation` class remains as you have given it in your question:

```
public class Operation {

    private Collection<BusinessEntity> getBusinessEntities() {
        //...
    }

    public void conduct(User user) {
        ConcreteOperationRoutine routine = 
            new ConcreteOperationRoutine(UUID.randomUUID(), user);

        routine.preExecute();

        for(BusinessEntity entity: getBusinessEntities())
            routine.midExecute(entity);

        routine.postExecute();

    }
}
```

Comment: I never thought about using dedicated classes to carry out logging, great stuff! However, as its name suggests, `routineSpecificLogDataObj` is routine-specific, and as such, would have to be made accessible to the `LoggingHelper` sub-classes in order to be defined by them. This means giving that field a visibility less restrictive than `private`, taking us back to square one.

Comment: Additionally, declaring a class as a "helper" for work that it itself carries out through its implementation of an interface seems a bit odd; it seems much more logical to define `LoggingHelper`as an inner class (so it is actually modeled as a helper) inside `OperationRoutine`

Comment: If your `routineSpecificLogDataObj` for each routine is always subclassing a specific class or implements a specific interface, you can use the above structure, and you can provide a setter and a getter for this field to be assigned a specific object at runtime.

Comment: Or, else, you can always use your original code in your question, and instead of using `protected` fields, you can restrict them to `private`, and provide protected/public setters and getters to them.

Comment: `routineSpecificLogDataObj` is just an object that `ConcreteOperationRoutine` happens to declare to be defined as, or to hold, the data that it will use (along with `parentOperationRunId` and `parentOperationRunCommencingUserId`) to log its work. Sorry for the confusion, I've updated the question to clarify such.

Comment: Redeclaring the fields in question as `private` and making them accessible with `protected` or `public` getters is one of the changes that I regarded as  "purely dogmatic in nature", given  the purpose of the fields and the fact that they're declared also declared as `final`.

Comment: @Kevin Taking into consideration this answer, your first comment in this answer, and your last comment in this answer, you can use the code of this answer, and provide a getter and a setter for the field `routineSpecificLogDataObj` in `LoggingHelper`. This is not final, its purpose is for logging, and with the setter and getter it will be available from all the `ConcreteOperationRoutine` classes. Moreover, If you don't like the name `LoggingHelper` (I don't), then you can rename it to `OperationRoutineLogging` or something better.

Answer (score 0):

If your `UUID` and `User` objects are needed for other processing reasons also by `preExecute`, `midExecute` and `postExecute` methods, apart from logging, then you should consider creating a class hosting all this functionality.

You would have the interface `OperationRoutine` with the definitions of the methods to implement:

```
public interface OperationRoutine {
    public abstract void preExecute();
    public abstract void midExecute(BusinessEntity entity);
    public abstract void postExecute();
}
```

And the `ConcreteOperationRoutine` class would provide also the logging capability, so, all the fields can be declared as private, as the methods that are using them are all methods of this class:

```
public class ConcreteOperationRoutine implements OperationRoutine {
    private Object routineSpecificLogDataObj;

    private final UUID parentOperationId;
    private final User parentOperationRunCommencingUser;

    protected ConcreteOperationRoutine(UUID parentOperationId, User parentOperationRunCommencingUser) {
        this.parentOperationId = parentOperationId;
        this.parentOperationRunCommencingUser = parentOperationRunCommencingUser;
    }

    protected void conductRoutineSpecificLoggingAct(int codeInt) {
        /*
         Code which logs work carried in out in an execute method(),
         using routineSpecificLogDataObj, parentOperationRunId,
         and parentOperationRunCommencingUser
        */
    }

    public void preExecute() {
        //...
        conductRoutineSpecificLoggingAct(0);
    }

    public void midExecute(BusinessEntity entity) {
        //...
        conductRoutineSpecificLoggingAct(1);
    }

    public void postExecute() {
        //...
        conductRoutineSpecificLoggingAct(2);
    }
}
```

And finally, your `Operation` class would be exactly the same as in your question:

```
public class Operation {

    private Collection<BusinessEntity> getBusinessEntities() {
        //...
    }

    public void conduct(User user) {
        ConcreteOperationRoutine routine = 
            new ConcreteOperationRoutine(UUID.randomUUID(), user);

        routine.preExecute();

        for(BusinessEntity entity: getBusinessEntities())
            routine.midExecute(entity);

        routine.postExecute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Representing the functionality of a routine as an interface is ideal, and in fact is what I've done in my production code. I still use of a routine base class however, since (as stated in the original post) each routine makes use of both`parentOperationRunId` and `parentOperationRunCommencingUser`, as well as routine-specific data (represented by `routineSpecificLogDataObj`) in the logging of its work. Given that the former 2 fields are utilized by every routine, I think it makes more sense to declare those fields in a base class than it does to redundantly define them in each routine.

Comment: OK, but what happens with `routineSpecificLogDataObj`? Will it be a member of every different routine? Or it's only part of this specific routine, along with the method `conductRoutineSpecificLoggingAct(int codeInt)`?

Comment: If a 'routineSpecificLogDataObj' is always present in your routines, then you should consider creating a class or an interface that defines its functionality. This would allow you declare a `routineSpecificLogDataObj` field in your `AbstractOperationRoutine` pushing always the method `conductRoutineSpecificLoggingAct(int codeInt)` to your `AbstractOperationRoutine`.

Comment: Why did you answer with two separate answers? (it's not against the rules, I'm simply curious)

Comment: They are 2 different alternatives and I thought they should be presented separately. And after that, I think it's better this way if someone wants to choose one of them, up-vote for one of them and down-vote  (maybe) for the other one.

Comment: @sanastasiadis Each routine may define, produce, or retrieve data of arbitrary type and cardinality that will be utilized (with `parentOperationId` and `parentOperationRunCommencingUser`) to the log its work; `ConcreteOperationRoutine` just so happens to declare such data as, or hold such data in,`routineSpecificLogDataObj`. Similarly, `conductRoutineSpecificLoggingAct` is just a logging method defined specifically for`ConcreteOperationRoutine`; given that each routine operates on a unique type of data, standardizing the way they log their work would not be possible.